# Field StandardValue vs DefaultValue vs FallbackValue vs InheritValue vs InnerValue

Tags: sitecore-api

The parameters of the `GetValue` methods of the `Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field` class enable developers to restrict the origin of the returned value to the Fields:

- StandardValue
- DefaultValue
- FallbackValue
- InheritValue
- InnerValue

What are the differences between each of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Inner value: the "raw" value (as you can see in the editor)
- Standard value: value inherited from Standard Values of the template
- Fallback value: value inherited through field fallback
- Inherit value: value inherited from original item (cloning)
- Default value: (thanks Klaus) this will be the value in the "default value" field of the field's item, which you find in the tree underneath your template item
  [image]

ps: field.Value will call this function will all parameters `true`.

Comment: For the default value - on the template field, you can find a default value field - this will be the Default Value

Comment: Great Answer Gato, don't forget to update your answer with the information from Klaus. As an aside, I would also think about adding a screen shot of oh where that default value is located. Just a thought. =)